# Двунаправленный поиск в графе на java

Tags: java, алгоритм, графы

Как его реализовать,может кто нибудь показать?Я знаю это это поиск с двух сторон.Но это должно происходить одновременно с обоих сторон или сначала с одной стороны,а потом с другой?И как это реализовать?
О двунаправленном поиске просто мало инфы в интернете по сравнению с поиском в ширину,глубину ипрочих

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search

Comment: Там нет ни примера кода,ни псевдокода.Ну и это на английском,а его я не знаю

Comment: Там есть и русский. Кто мешает его выбрать?

Answer (score 0):

Например, так - выполняете одновременно по одному шагу поиска в ширину из начальной и конечной вершины.

Если поиск из начальной встречает пометку вершины, выполненную поиском из конечной, или наоборот - встретились два поиска.